# How to release VM:ImageIO_GIF_Data using ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, animated-gif

I use [OLImage](https://github.com/ondalabs/OLImageView) in the viewB's drawRect method to load a local gif image. I use a normal `ViewA` to push `ViewB`, and pop `ViewB` repeatedly. After about 20 times, my app crashed after received several `memory warnings.` 
I use instrument to monitor the memory usage, and you can see the result below.
[image: Instrument statics]

My code to load gif is like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet OLImageView *gifImageView;


    if (!self.gifImageView.image) {
        self.gifImageView.image = [OLImage imageNamed:@"好.gif"];
        [self.gifImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.gifImageView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)]];
    }
```

I'm use `ARC`, I think the gif data should be released by iOS when `ViewB` popped. Or at least when my app received memory warnings.
Am I doing something wrong?
OR this can be more general question that how to release `VM memory in ARC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's maybe an issue of OLImage itself. I made a pull request for this issue. Check out the [commit](https://github.com/ondalabs/OLImageView/pull/35) here if you are interested.